# Angular 2, when to reference module in appmodule and when to reference in component?

Tags: angular

I am trying to create my first application with Angular2, when I need to use Http service, I would need to add it to my ngModule using

```
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'
```

Then reference it in the imports, after that I need to reference it in service.ts file like this:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http'
```

So far so good. Now why when I need to use ngModel, I would need to reference FormsModule only in the ngModule like this:

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
```

Why not referencing the FormsModule as well in the component file like we did with the Http module?

Am I missing something? Thanks for any help.

Comment: IImport what you want** is the core concept of angular2

Comment: LOL.. I know I can import what I want. The question is, why is it not necessary to import FormsModule in the component, since am using it there. We imported Http to the service because we use it there, why FormsModule wasn't used in component.

Comment: where you will refer to the FormsModule in your application?

Comment: I referred to it in the app module file. But I am using the `[(ngModel)]` in the component file. It works without referencing the FormsModule in the component file. How did it work while it's not referenced there?

Comment: with these three lines of import statements we cant help. update the post with more details

Comment: First you tell me my question is useless, and now you want me to update it.. now you modified your original comment to delete the "useless" word.. It's ok, I will wait for someone else to help. Thank you :)

Comment: Http is a service. FormsModule is a module. They are apples and oranges. You can't 'reference' a module in component file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http` is a service. Services need to be imported when you need it (i.e. dependency injection in a component constructor).

`ngModel` is a directive. Directives and components need to be declared in the `ngModule` definition, but they don't need to be included in the component definition file.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent, MyDirective, etc]
})
```

Components and Directives need to be exported, if they are going to be available to modules that import them:

Child Module:

```
@NgModule({
    // MyComponent and MyDirective are available to Sub-Components
    declarations: [MyComponent, MyDirective, etc],
    // MyComponent is public to the module, MyDirective is private
    exports: [MyComponent]
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

Parent Module:

```
@NgModule({
    // MyComponent is available in sub-components in ParentModule
    imports: [ChildModule]
})
export class ParentModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. But when we need to use a component in another component, we once again import it in the other component, why not doing the same for FormsModule?

Comment: When you need to use a component in another component, an "import" is not needed. For FormsModule, the NgModel directive was 'exported' so when you import the module, no further qualification is necessary

Comment: How about pipes and interfaces, I need to import these right? They are not declared on the module level, right?\

Comment: pipes, components, and directives are declared at the module level. interfaces should not be.

Comment: what about a service that uses http, do i reference it in the module, or the component that uses it? it's so confusing to know which one to reference where

Comment: a service that uses http should be referenced in the `providers` array in the module definition. Then it can be dependency injected into any component that needs it.  In order to use http, your module should import the HttpModule.  Services in the providers array of your module definition are automatically available to other modules through dependency injection once that other module imports your module.

Comment: I have referenced the service in the providers array in the root component, by importing it there, and referencing it in the providers, however, if I wanna use it in a sub component, I will need to import it once again there and use it. Is that correct behavior? Without the import statement in the sub component, i will have compile errors that the service is not there.